# Reload page using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, reload

Is there a way to reload a page using prototype (or redirect to itself)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't need a Javascript Library for this. A simple:

```
window.location.reload();
```

or

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

should suffice.

Comment: window.location.reload() is better since it will work even if there is an anchor (#) This is not the case for window.location.href = window.location.href;

Answer (score 5):

I doubt it. It seems rather pointless to write a helper function for something as simple as [`location.reload(true);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location) when it really isn't used very often.

Comment: Where is this boolean parameter actually specified or documented? MDN mentions it only on that page, but without a formal documentation on [`Location.prototype.reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload). Neither [WhatWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#location) nor [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/browsers.html#location) mention it, either. It appeared to have been introduced in [this revision](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location$compare?locale=en-US&to=370593&from=370587). It _does_ seem to work, though.

Comment: It’s also weird that that MDN article [didn’t mention the `true` parameter](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location$revision/34188) at the time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```